# gcc fails with spawn: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, cygwin

I downloaded
[Ruben’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256138) build of
[Cygwin GCC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-release).

However upon running it seems unable to compile any files

```
$ touch foo.c

$ gcc foo.c
gcc: error: spawn: No such file or directory
```

As a workaround, I found this to work

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc foo.c
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same problem on Cygwin64, and the solution was PATH related..kinda.

Turns out, there are copies of gcc in /usr/bin and /bin (at least, there is in my install).

Executing /bin/gcc failed with the error above -- I'm guessing due to incorrectly assumed relative paths???

Executing /usr/bin/gcc works as expected!

In my case, the "problem" was that I had inadvertently injected "/bin" into my PATH environment variable, resulting in /bin/gcc being executed, instead of /usr/bin/gcc.  Removing the "/bin" from the path solved the problem.

Still unclear why there are two gcc binaries (which appear to be identical) in different places... but maybe the Cygwin gurus can answer that; or maybe my installation is just foo-barred.

Comment: It's also worth checking for `g++` and `pkg-config` on your path.  Per the [installation](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/INSTALL) instructions, `CC`, `CXX`, and `PKG_CONFIG` are checked.  I was getting this error because I had a MinGW version of `g++` my path from a different installation and was getting the same answer.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem and solved it by installing the g++ package in addition to gcc-core

Comment: this should be in comment.

Comment: That could be an answer too. Helped me to solve `spawn: no such file...` problem.

Comment: I was given the same - pretty useless/misleading error.
In my case I had updated the Cygwin g++ package but not the gcc package.
So the solution was similar: update the second package to the same version.

Comment: Worked for me with Cygwin64 and Netbeans 12.2 .

Answer (score 3):

Ruben's builds are **not** Cygwin GCC packages, rather they are cross-compilers which run on various platforms but target native Windows using the MinGW-w64 toolchain.

In any case, you shouldn't be using them on Cygwin.  If you want to compile Cygwin executables, install the gcc4 packages; if you want to cross-compile for Windows, install the mingw64-i686-gcc (for Win32) or mingw64-x86_64-gcc (for Win64) packages instead.

Answer (score 2):

Gcc isn't really the compiler. It's a front end program that orchestrates the execution of any necessary compiler, assembler, and linker components. Typically these others are separately compiled programs.

So, gcc is trying (kind of) to tell you that it can't *find* the compiler.  I guess it needs to be on your PATH or in an expected location.

If you are executing this from a Windows DOS box then it definitely needs a windows PATH setting.

I like to [install Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html), making sure to include **rxvt**.  At that point, you can configure a purely sh(1) path and your environment is rather more civilized.

Comment: This is the key. If you add "-v" to your gcc command, you'll probably see the actual tool it's trying to run (but can't find). In my case I was missing cc1plus, which I needed to install from the g++ package in cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I tried to extract a couple of executables from cygwin installation dirctory and copied them into another location.

strace shows me the file which was not found by spawn:

```
/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/cc1.exe
```

When I copied cc1.exe into the location relative to

```
<dir with sh.exe and cpp.exe>/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/cc1.exe
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs whenever cygwin cc can't find a required file.

For those running stuff within cygwin's bin directly **from** a Windows shell, a gotcha to watch out for is that Windows allow you to run programs from the command line like this:

```
e:cyg/bin/gcc -flags
```

Notice that there is no slash between `e:` and `cyg`.

So this command would successfully **start** cygwin gcc from the Windows shell, but halfway through the run it  will error out because some *component(s)* of `gcc` will utilize  the first argument of the input `e:cyg/bin/gcc` and unlike mingw, this **is not a valid path** for cygwin gcc.

This can be fixed simply by changing the command to:

```
e:/cyg/bin/gcc -flags
```

Notice the slash in between `e:` and `cyg`.

---

A similar gotcha is due to Windows allowing paths like `e:/../folder1` as an alternative to `e:/folder1`.  Windows does not give you an error if you are at the root folder and try to go *up* another folder using `..`.

So you could **start running** cygwin gcc using the command:

```
e:/../cyg/bin/gcc -flags
```

..or even:

```
e:/../../../../../../../../../cyg/bin/gcc -flags
```

However, it would fail halfway with `gcc: error: spawn: No such file or directory` because some *component(s)* of cygwin gcc would attempt to run `gcc` using the first argument of the command input itself, and unlike mingw, `e:/../cyg/bin/gcc` is not recognized as a valid path by cygwin because you are going *up* a folder when there's no folder to go up to.

As like above, this can be fixed by keeping the path valid:

```
e:/cyg/bin/gcc -flags
```

Comment: Could such mess happen when you chain h files? Namely the C file includes an h file which include another one. All using relative paths. VS 2017 is OK and parse paths correcty. Yet GCC fails.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the source file extension is in lowercase (i.e. main.c, **not** main.C):

```
$ gcc -o main main.C
$ gcc: error: spawn: No such file or directory

$ gcc -o main main.c
$ # all good
```

This only refers to the case of the extension as given to the gcc, the actual source file can have the extension in whatever case you want.

Explanation: This is from my experimenting with cygwin and gcc, I don't know the actual reason for this behavior.